# Which Varna and sects are allowed to wear tripundra?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, shaiva-siddhanta, tilak

**the agnivesya grihsutra suggests that only Kshatriyas,vaishayas, and shudras are allowed to wear a tripundra(1.18). Some Vaishnavas use it to say that a brahmin shouldn't be allowed to wear a tripundra. Can some scriptural inferences confirm whether tripundra can be worn by Brahmins?**

Comment: Anyone can wear tripundra 

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a brahmana can have tripunda. In fact, he should have more tripundas than others.

> 20. O **Brāhmaṇa, a Brāhmaṇa should always have twelve Puṇḍras**.[3] O son, Kṣatriyas should have four. It is prescribed (in Smṛtis) that
>     Vaiśyas should have two Puṇḍras. It is laid down that women and Śūdras
>     should have only one Puṇḍra.
> 21. The following are the parts of the body where a Brāhmaṇa should have his twelve sacred marks: forehead, belly, chest, hump of the
>     neck, arms, ears, back, right side and lower part of the spine, and
>     head, O sinless one.
> 22. A Kṣatriya should have the sacred marks on his forehead, chest and the arms; a Vaiśya on his forehead and chest and a Śūdra and women
>     should wear the sacred mark on the forehead.

> **[The Application of Tripundra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371681.html)**

According to [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225963.html) people of all varnas can have Tripundra.

> 9. People of all varṇas and Āśramas shall put on Tripuṇḍra on the forehead or dust their bodies with the mantras mentioned in the Jābāla-Upaniṣad or if no mantra is used they shall do the same with reverence.

Devi Bhagavatam say that it is necessary for a brahmin to have Tripundra.

> **Unless the Brāhmaṇas use the curved Tripuṇḍras, their meditation won’t be successful; they will not have liberation, knowledge, nor their asceticism would bear any fruit.** As the Śūdras have no right in the study of the Vedas, so the Brāhmaṇs have not any right to perform the worship of Śiva, etc., unless they use the Tripuṇḍras.

> **Devi Bhagwatam 11:12 21-22**

Answer (score 3):

Here are the proofs that a Bramhin can wear Tripundra

> The Bramhins and others , the householders and such persons should
> apply Bhasma in 3 stripes(Tripundra) according to direction set forth
> in the agamas. It is laid down in the scriptures that 3 stripes of
> Bhasma may be drawn in 5,8,16 or 32 parts of the body. (Kamika Agama
> Part 1 Page 63 Verses 70-71)
>
> The God Siva is always hidden under the cover of ashes; so the Saivas,
> the devotees of Siva are to use the Tripundra. The Brahmanas are to
> use daily this Tripundra. Brahma is the Prime Brâhmin. When He used
> Tripundra on His forehead, what need to tell, then, that every Brâhman
> ought always to use it! Never fail, out of error, to besmear your body
> with the ashes as prescribed in the Vedas and worship the Siva Lingam.
> The Sannyasins are to apply Tripundra on their forehead, arms, chest,
> uttering the Triyamvaka mantra with Om prefixed and also the five
> lettered mantra of Siva “Om Namah Sivâya.” The Brahmâchâris should use
> Tripundra of ashes, obtained from their own fire, uttering the mantra
> “Triyayusam Jamadagneh,” etc., or the mantra “Medhâvî”, etc (Devi
> Bhagavatam [1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch09.htm))

Answer (score 1):

On the Contrary, Baudhayana Grihya sutra clearly precribes the Tiryak Tripundra (with three lines) or Eka pundra (with one line) for Brahmanas

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sri Shiva Purana 1.24.11-12.:

> **Śiva, Viṣṇu, Umā, Lakṣmī, goddess of speech and other gods and goddesses, brahmins, kṣatriyas, vaiśyas and persons of mixed castes and hill tribes have observed Tripuṇḍra and dusting (Uddhūlana) always.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..